# Having two UITableViews in one UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to have two different UITableViews in one UITableViewController, and only one of them will be shown at a time. The parent view controller works as their datasource. I load data for both of the tables when the VC first loads so that the user doesn't have to wait when switching between the tables.

I add the second table view programatically, but then I lose all the styles that I implemented for the first table view, which I did in storyboard. More importantly, I don't have a prototype cell for the second table view.

Question: How do I clone the first tableView to make a second tableView?

CurrentCode:

```
//    Set up Recent Posts Table
    [self.recentPostsTable setDelegate:self];
    [self.recentPostsTable setDataSource:self];
    [self.recentPostsTable setTag:0];

//    Set up hot Posts Table
    UITableView *hotPostsTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.recentPostsTable.frame style:self.recentPostsTable.style];
    [hotPostsTable setDelegate:self];
    [hotPostsTable setDataSource:self];
    [hotPostsTable setTag:1];
    self.hotPostsTable = hotPostsTable;

    [self fetchPosts:RECENT_POSTS_TABLE_TAG limit:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NUM_RECENT_POSTS_IN_ONE_BATCH] skip:@0];
    [self fetchPosts:HOT_POSTS_TABLE_TAG limit:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NUM_HOT_POSTS_IN_ONE_BATCH] skip:@0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't actually want 2 `UITableViews`, but rather 2 `UITableViewDataSources`. Make two classes that each implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods in the way that you were going to make the separate table views behave. Then when you want to "switch between table views", simply assign one of the 2 data sources to `self.tableView.dataSource`.

Comment: You don't need two data sources. Just base the one set of data source and delegate methods on one of two arrays based on one of two modes.

Comment: The reason I wanted two separate UITableViews was that I don't want the user wait for rendering new tablecells. If I simply swap datasources on the fly for the same tableview, every time I change the source the tableview will be re-rendered, no?

Comment: If the data is still in memory then it will just refresh the cells; no biggie. And like @rmdaddy said, you can boil this down to two arrays and just keep a reference to both arrays so that the data stays in memory.

Comment: But they would still have to wait for the initial loading of the second table view, wouldn't they?

Comment: @MaximusS Yes, they would have to wait. But it would take about 0.04 seconds. Try it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly the solution!